# jQuery Raty stars with score. jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know how to add the score to the star, something like this:

[image]

I thought about making the numbers in Photoshop, but then how it's going to scale on different size screens?

Also thought about setup JS to calculate width. However it seems for me as a complex one.

If anyone know a quick workaround / hack / or may be out of box solution. That would be perfect.

Comment: What library are you using? Can you create a fiddle with the code that you are using?

Comment: jQuery mobile raty... will do as time allows

Answer (score 0):

Well I just created an image and put it underneath the Raty...

Not the best approach, but it did work

Answer (score 0):

You can create a placeholder for each star.
Use the same with for start and it place holder.

Comment: What do you mean by placeholder? HTML placeholder?

Comment: Placeholder is just a element, like `div`.